# Paradox after an evening of hold-em with 5 to 7 players

Tags: texas-hold-em, cash-game, home-game

After almost a hundred hands, I would have expected that each player's chip stack at the end of the night would be just as likely to be odd as even. Instead, almost always, zero or two players have odd stacks.

We play with an buy-in stack of 40 chips per player. A player who runs out of chips buys chips from another player who has plenty. Individual bets are up to five chips. No blinds, but dealer antes a number of chips equal to the number of players.

Any ideas?

Comment: do all players have chips at the end of the night?

Comment: If it is 5 then 4 odd would be as rare as 0 odd.

Comment: We quit after 3 hours and all players play all hands. All players have chips at quitting time.

Comment: You played several hundred hands in 3 hours.  That is over one hand a minute.

Comment: I meant to say "almost a hundred."

Comment: At first thought I think this is coincidental if you are playing no-limit @PhilFreedenberg. If you are playing limit it might require some more thought.